# Trouble setting up ganache for smart contracts

Tags: node.js

https://iamdefinitelyahuman.medium.com/getting-started-with-brownie-part-1-9b2181f4cb99

I followed this link to try and download ganache, but this command, 'npm install -g ganache-cli' is not working. Instead it shows the error below. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? It also says I have a permission errors, but I'm not too sure where to fix this. I am using VS Code.

---

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 0):

```
  sudo npm install -g ganache-cli
```

If ganache installation gives an error try this.

```
   sudo npm install ganache@beta --global
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a permissions error. It looks like you don't have write permission to `usr/local/lib/node_modules/`. There are a variety of ways to fix that, but don't use sudo, as it is not secure. Use a group instead.